# Authorization has been denied for this request when sending request through Mobile Safari for subdomains

Tags: c#, angular, oauth, authorization, mobile-safari

I have implemented a C# WebApi with OAuth:

```
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = false,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
```

This works great throughout my application on Computer and mobile web.
But some requests are denied on mobile safari on iphone, also chrome iphone. When I inspect the request in Safari Development mode and take the request parameters to Postman with same token, the request passes.

I only have this issue on subdomains.

I have tried changing allowed domains but no effect, other calls also work.

In Angular I do the following request just after I set the Auth Token to LocalStorage, it is part of a custom RouteGuard:

```
canAccessWizard(): Observable<boolean> {
var headers = this.baseService.getHeaders();
return this.http.get<boolean>(this.baseService.restApiUrl + this.userBaseUrl + 'CanAccessWizard/', { headers: headers, responseType: 'json' });}
```

Where getHeaders code looks like:

```
getHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
let authToken = this.auth.getAccessToken();
if (authToken == null) {
  this.auth.logout();
}
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(authToken).access_token);
return headers;}
```

If I skip this call/Guard and continue to the page the next request with Authorization passes all the time.

I Expect all call to authorize with same token.

Comment: Is this a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS issue?

Comment: @Douglas I don not think so, because it's from sub.domain.com to sub.domain.com. And other requests work fine.

Comment: Hm, not sure then. Are there any other error messages that could explain it?